# Android microphone application

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, microphone

Does anyone have any idea how to create an application on an android as a microphone? Like speaking into the android device and it will amplify the voice out?

---

Yes , I agree .
However , I have to do this as this is my final year project assigned by my supervisor . So i have to do it by hook or by crook . ):

I have already created the application to amplify the voice out from my android device when i speak to it. But there's echo , very high frequency and sensitive to the background .

Do you guys have any solution to this ?

Comment: No, as already explained some delay is inherent in the system architecture.  Shorter buffers may reduce it, but at the expense of reliability.

Answer (score 1):

You really mean a *megaphone*, as in a self-contained voice amplification device.

Sure, technically it's possible, but there are several reasons to not bother. Most importantly, the amplifiers and speakers on handheld devices cannot match the volume you can already achieve with your voice. Also, you would have to work out the feedback challenges - definitely solvable (phase shifts, minor delays, etc.) but effort nonetheless.

Bottom line: I don't think it's worth doing because even if you make it work, someone standing next to you will be able to shout louder than your handheld device can amplify your voice. Not trying to be negative here, just realistic.

Comment: Additionally, given the delay of the audio path in many Android devices, trying to talk through such a thing can be extremely disconcerting.

Comment: It would at least help to prevent acoustic feedback, though! {grin}

Comment: Even with headphones so that there is no acoustic feedback path, it's quite a mental challenge to talk when you hear yourself with a certain range of delay.